# Running A Script From Parent Domain Server To Child Domain With Child Domain Credentials

Tags: powershell, domain, windows-server-2019, task-scheduler

I have written a Powershell script which checks the OS and does some security scans. The server we run this script from is a member of the Parent domain of my system. I need to run this script from that server against all the machines on my Child Domain. I have created an account on the Child domain which has admin privileges to allow for scanning on all the machines on the Child Domain. The script using -ComputerName with a variable that is an array that lists of the computers to scan.

I have made a Task in Task Scheduler to run this scan on a routine basis. The task runs launches the script without a problem. I have the setting to run the script at the highest privilege level checked. For the credentials for the task I put in the account for the Child Domain I setup for scanning.

When I check the log it says the account is running without local administrative rights. Here is what confuses me. Since the account I created and specified doesn't have administrative rights on the Parent Computer but does on the Child Domain computer does that matter? And for some reason when it runs the script against each computer on the Child Domain it uses "COMPUTERNAME.LOCAL" instead of the typical "COMPUTER". Should I be using the FQDN for this when I specify the -ComputerName ? And also can I run this script from the Parent Domain to the Child Domain like this or do I need to make permissions or configuration changes? The script does have a parameter called "-AltCredential" that pops a UAC box for credentials but I don't want to hardcode a password nor have any idea on how to fill out that box since its an automated script.

Comment: Which PowerShell version do you have available?

Comment: @Turdie PowerShell 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell Remoting, which is supported by PowerShell 5.PowerShell Remoting is a feature that allows you to run PowerShell commands or script on a remote computer. It relies on the Windows Remote Management (WinRM) service, which uses the WS-Management protocol for communication.

1. First you enable powershell remoting with command
   `Enable-PSRemoting`. Also make sure that the network requirements
   for PowerShell Remoting between the two dc's are in place.
2. Then you set the TrustedHosts which are allowed.
   For example
   `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "ClientComputer1,ClientComputer2" - Force`
3. Then restart the WinRM service `Restart-Service WinRM`

Then running a script remotely goes like this:
`Invoke-Command -FilePath c:\scripts\test.ps1 -ComputerName childdc` (you can also enter an ip address behind computername)

Another cool thing i wanted to highlight what you can do with PowerShell Remoting is opening a remote powershell session using the command `Enter-PSSession`